# Django - Use one models primary key in another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, primary-key

I want to use one model's primary key in another model in django.
Here is what I want to do-

```
class Verse(models.Model): 
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User') 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400) 
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag) 
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to use this model's primary key to another model in order to check if the user has voted.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    #get verse id
    #get vote value
```

I want to be able to use the Verse Model, and the 'votes' column if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse you can use it.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    verse = models.ForeignKey(Verse)
```

To access votes value you simply have to write:

```
User.verse.votes
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use too:

```
models.ForeignKey('aplicationname.modelname')
```